# Vue TypeError: Cannot read property '_wrapper' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to write some project, using Vue. When I try to add new item to array in 'data' (which should start re-render), I get this error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_wrapper' of undefined.

What does that mean?

```
[...some layout...]
       <a @click="addElement" id="addBtn">Add</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
      props: [
          'routes'
      ],
      data: function () {
          routes: this.props.routes
      },
      methods: {
          addElement: function () {
              this.routes.push( {[...some object...]} );
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `data` in Vuejs is a function that returns an object. Your code is not returning an object.
- Your prop name is same the data name. They should be different.

Try the following code:

```
[...some layout...]
       <a @click="addElement" id="addBtn">Add</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
      props: [
          'routes'
      ],
      data: function () {
         return {         // Object being returned
             storedRoutes: this.routes   // props can be directly accessed using `this`
         }
      },
      methods: {
          addElement: function () {
              this.storedRoutes.push( {[...some object...]} );
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```

I also changed `this.props.routes` to `this.routes`

Comment: Thank you for response! I'm sorry for those mistakes, I am beginner in Vue. I changed code as you told, but the error remained the same. Then I made some experimental changes and it's look like something is wrong with layout (becouse if I render only ```<div v-for="route in routes">{{ route.Title }}<div>``` and button - the program work correctly). Now I trying to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Hi, if you feel that there is something wrong in the HTML, then, you'll have to add that code in your question. Maybe then, the community can help you out with more changes.

Comment: It was a layout written by my colleague, so I just rewrote it from scratch. I changed the controversial points (like calls to non-existent methods) and now everything works. It looks a bit like magic, but the problem is solved. Thank you :)

Comment: @БратиславМоргунов Glad I could be of help. Please consider accepting this answer so that it helps other members of the community